# How to create a bitmap whose dimension is the central square of the screen?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, object-detection

### Context & Goal

I'm building a real-time object detection app. To achieve this, I need a `bitmap` to send to the recognition algorithm. I have an activity displaying the camera output in full screen, but I'm trying to operate the recognition **only on the central square of the screen**. So I need a bitmap with those dimensions and position, corresponding to the the central square of the phone screen.

### What I have tried

```java
    @Override
    public void onPreviewSizeChosen(final Size size, final int rotation) {

        /* some code... */
    
        // Width of the screen (larger than the height), for my phone it's 4032
        previewWidth    = size.getWidth();
        // Height of the screen, for my phone it's 1980
        previewHeight   = size.getHeight();

        sensorOrientation = rotation - getScreenOrientation();

        // The bitmap which will be used to the recognition, dimension : full screen of the phone
        rgbFrameBitmap  = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth, previewHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);

        // squared bitmap 320x320, required size for the recognition algorithm
        croppedBitmap   = Bitmap.createBitmap(cropSize, cropSize, Config.ARGB_8888);

        // bitmap to croppedBitmap transform Matrix
        frameToCropTransform =
                ImageUtils.getTransformationMatrix(
                        previewWidth, previewHeight,
                        cropSize, cropSize,
                        sensorOrientation, MAINTAIN_ASPECT);

        cropToFrameTransform = new Matrix();
        frameToCropTransform.invert(cropToFrameTransform);

        trackingOverlay = (OverlayView) findViewById(R.id.tracking_overlay);
        trackingOverlay.addCallback(
                new DrawCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void drawCallback(final Canvas canvas) {
                        tracker.draw(canvas, isDebug());
                    }
                });
        tracker.setFrameConfiguration(previewWidth, previewHeight, sensorOrientation);
       
    }

@Override
    protected void processImage() {

        trackingOverlay.postInvalidate();

        if (computingDetection) {
            readyForNextImage();
            return;
        }
        computingDetection = true;

        // THE LINE I CAN'T FIGURE OUT
        // I try to set width and height = previewHeight (1980 for my phone so a square)
        // and to move it down by (previewWidth-previewHeight)/2 so it goes in the middle of the screen
        rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), 0, previewWidth, 0, (previewWidth-previewHeight)/2, previewHeight, previewHeight);

        readyForNextImage();

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(croppedBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(rgbFrameBitmap, frameToCropTransform, null);

        // Saved set to true, so I can check what the bitmap sent to the recognition algorithm looks like
        if (SAVE_PREVIEW_BITMAP) {
            ImageUtils.saveBitmap(croppedBitmap);
        }

        runInBackground(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Here we send the bitmap to the recognition algorithm to perform real-time detection
                        final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = detector.recognizeImage(croppedBitmap);


/* some code ... */

}
```

If I replace the `(previewWidth-previewHeight)/2` by `0` as the `y` parameter of  `rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels()` function, I manage to perform real-time recognition in a square on top of the screen, as I want unless it's not centered. But as soon as I set the `y` parameter to `(previewWidth-previewHeight)/2`, this is the error I get when it tries to save the bitmap :

```
W/ImageReader_JNI: Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers
```

How can I get the bitmap to be centered in the middle of the screen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Self solved

There are two thing I misunderstood on the above code.

First, I mixed up the `x` and the `y` parameters of the `rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels()` function, but in any case this was just adding some black space to the bitmap. To obtain the center of the screen, the parameter to change is the `offset`, like this :

```java
int x = (previewWidth-previewHeight)/2;
rgbFrameBitmap.setPixels(getRgbBytes(), x, previewWidth, 0, 0, previewHeight, previewHeight);
```

Besides, as we send the `croppedBitmap` to the recognition algorithm, which is the `rgbFrameBitmap` cropped to 320x320 thanks to the matrix `frameToCropTransform`, I had to update this :

```java
frameToCropTransform =
                ImageUtils.getTransformationMatrix(
                        previewWidth, previewHeight,
                        cropSize, cropSize,
                        sensorOrientation, MAINTAIN_ASPECT);
```

into this :

```java
frameToCropTransform =
                ImageUtils.getTransformationMatrix(
                        previewHeight, previewHeight,
                        cropSize, cropSize,
                        sensorOrientation, MAINTAIN_ASPECT);
```

as `rgbFrameBitmap` is now a square of dimensions `previewHeight`x`previewHeight`

Answer (score 0):

**Horizontal Screen**

To get the central square area of a screen, compare `height` and `width` of the screen in pixels. Usually for desktop systems `width` is bigger, and I will assume this is the case.

Get the difference `width`-`height`, divide by two and call it `x`.
Finally draw a rectangle from (x, 0) to (x+height, height).

**More General**

The side length of the square will be `length = min(width,height)`
The coordinates of the square will be

```
x = (width-length)/2
y = (height-length)/2
```

Finally draw a rectangle from (x, y) to (x+length, y+length).

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. This is exactly what I'm trying to do with (previewWidth-previewHeight)/2 as y parameter of bitmap.setpixels() function right? Otherwise I must be missing something